# Handle fault event in mx.data.DataService while background sync?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, dataservice

We are using objects that at times need to sync up with the server via
the mx.data.DataService, The problem is in case of explicit method
invocation over the dataservice object we are able to trap the fault
events using the fault handlers.

The problem arises when dataservice is sync'ing the object in
background. In case of a fault event (such as session timeout or
server down) the error is not trapped via the fault handler added on
the dataservice using the addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT).

Any suggestions on how to trap the fault events generated via
background sync invocations of the DataService?

Answer (score 0):

Try DataServiceFaultEvent.FAULT instead of FaultEvent.FAULT

Comment: DataServiceFaultEvent extends from FaultEvent and hence, does not make a difference (as expected).